# Can I avoid Maven deployed war version with timestamp in Archiva?

Tags: maven, archiva

In out project we are using using deployed war file in `/archiva-2.2.0/repositories/internal/com/xyz/1-SNAPSHOT/proj-1-20160204.122021-15.war` path using shell script to copy to jboss. However finding the latest build timestamp and build number is very difficult. Is there a way to avoid using timestamp while storing it in archiva like **proj-1-SNAPSHOT.war**?
I have already read about `<uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>` whcih is not supported in maven 3.

I am using archiva-2.2.0, maven-3.3.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this as it is a new finding, if I `wget http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8083/repository/internal/com/xyz/1-SNAPSHOT/proj-1-SNAPSHOT.war`. I get the latest deployed artifact in the archiva repository. So archiva does a 302 redirect to point to url of `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8083/repository/internal/com/xyz/1-SNAPSHOT/proj-1-20160204.122021-15.war` location and downloads the latest build. I am not sure if this works for other repositories like nexus or artifactory etc.

Ofcourse I will need a cron job to periodically clear of the stale snapshot artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Maven repositories wasn't designed to distribute deployable components, your continuous integration environment should take care of this. Jenkins has eg Archive Artifacts (native) and [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) which you can use to store and recover binaries in your pipelines.

But you can workaround this behavior changing the version of the `war` to a stable one - removing the `-SNAPSHOT` suffix. This will lead you with a predictable URL.